# Ajax Jquery getting error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

```
        var a = $('.level').find(":selected").attr('value');
        var b = $('.category').find(":selected").attr('value');
        var c = $('.topic').find(":selected").attr('value');
        var d = $('.question').val();

        $.ajax({
        url:     "http://localhost/2016/2016_02_15_Quiz/index.php/Admin/getthecompr/" + a + "/" + b + "/" + c,
        type:    "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '',
        success: function(data) {
            var id = data;

            $.ajax({
                url:     "http://localhost/2016/2016_02_15_Quiz/index.php/Admin/insert4/" + id[0]['id_comprehens'] + "/" + d,
                type:    "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: '',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Success");
                },
                error:   function() {
                    alert("Fail")
                }
            });
        },
        error:   function() {
            console.log('Paastoge');
        }
        });
    });
```

I got trouble making this nested-JQuery-Ajax. In the first Ajax, I take the value of compre_id that I want to use in second Ajax. In the second Ajax, I will insert the `id_comprhensive` and `question` in MySQL table. The Problem is, inserting data to SQL table is success. But, instead of displaying "success", fail alert does appear. Is there something problem with this code ?

Comment: And then, there is nothing appears in console log.

Comment: why an earth are you nesting lol :))

Comment: @madalinivascu maybe the first one is call to external API he cannot modify?
I mean, that could be valid scenario ;)

Comment: @entio yes localhost localhost :)))

Comment: @ZainabSafiyyahAl-habsyi post your php code of you ajaxed pages

Comment: what is the error??/

Comment: error:   function(a) {
                    alert(a.responseText.Message)
                }  .........use this code to get error in alert

Comment: post your controller and model methods here..

Comment: comment the line data :"",

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have solved the problem. The problem is the return value of my PHP.